# How to use "sed" commands in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: shell, jenkins, sed, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have to remove space between two words in pipeline log. here is pipeline code

```
echo "MyUserName: ${cause.userName}"
```

after this, output in log file is

```
MyUserName: [James Perera]
```

expected output in log file

```
MyUserName: [JamesPerera]
```

This is what I tryied

```
echo "MyUserName: ${cause.userName}"

sh """   ${cause.userName} sed 's/ //g' """
```

then output in log

```
MyUserName: [James Perera]
[Pipeline] sh
+ sed 's/ //g' '[James' 'Perera]'
sed: can't read [James: No such file or directory
sed: can't read Perera]: No such file or directory
```

Can someone help me to figure out this? Thanks in advance!

**Note**: The reason I want to remove space between 2 words is I have to pass that value as a single word to server. otherwise it will print 1 word in server ( "[James" )

Comment: I can't follow the Jenkins syntax, but at the commandline, you'd want `sed 's/ //g' <<< $var` or `echo $var | sed 's/ //g'` to get sed to place the edited $var string on stdout.   Instead you're placing the contents of the string as arguments to sed, which sed expects to be files named `[James` and `Perera]`

Comment: I am not sure what shell is running on your jenkins system, but if its is something like a bash or ksh you should be able to do *parameter substitution* and use `echo "MyUserName: ${cause.userName// /}"` .

Answer (score 0):

In bash you can achieve this by:

```
echo "MyUserName: ${cause.userName// /}"
```

Syntax of variable substring replacement:

```
${variablename//pattern/replacement}
```

In our case pattern is the space character we want to remove. And replacement is empty to delete any matches.